# AsyncTask delegate string issue

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an issue with delegating String from my AsyncTask.

Here's the code:

AsyncTask:

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String strings) {

    super.onPostExecute(strings);
    delegate.TaskCompletionResult(strings);

}
```

Delegate interface:

```
public interface TaskDelegate {
void TaskCompletionResult(String result);
}
```

and Main Activity:

```
public void TaskCompletionResult(String result) {

    object = parseJSON(result);

    listofObjects = jsonToList(object);
}
```

My error:

```
Process: ligagraczy.aplikacja.pl.ligagraczy, PID: 10749
                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void ligagraczy.aplikacja.pl.ligagraczy.TaskDelegate.TaskCompletionResult(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                  at ligagraczy.aplikacja.pl.ligagraczy.TestAsyncTask.onPostExecute(TestAsyncTask.java:68)
                                  at ligagraczy.aplikacja.pl.ligagraczy.TestAsyncTask.onPostExecute(TestAsyncTask.java:25)
                                  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
                                  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

I've tried to push some hardcoded strings, but the result is the same.

@EDIT:

I have this also in my AsyncTask:

```
private TaskDelegate delegate;


    protected TestAsyncTask(TaskDelegate delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }
```

and my MainActivity implements TaskDelegate

Comment: are you sure that **delegate** was initialized? Looks like the **delegate** is null. So you get this error

Comment: I think that I don't get. How to initialize it? I did 'delegate.TaskCompletionResult(strings)' in my async task

Comment: you should implement **TaskDelegate** for example create TaskDelegateImp.class  and somewhere in code write something like this  **TaskDelegate delegate = new TaskDelegateImp()**

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize the delegate in the constructor of your `AsyncTask` like this

```
    public class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {

        public TaskCompletionResult delegate;

        public YourAsyncTask(TaskCompletionResult delegate) {
            delegate = delegate;
        }
        ...
        public interface TaskDelegate {
               void TaskCompletionResult(String result);
        }
    }
```

Then in your `Activity`

```
    public class YourActivity extends Activity implements TaskDelegate {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            ...

            YourAsyncTask task = new YourAsyncTask(YourActivity.this);
            task.execute();
        }

        @Override
        public void TaskCompletionResult(String response) {
          ...
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks, but it cannot resolve symbol TaskCompletionResult. Should I create a class with that name?